# Datatables re-arrange elements on export to excel

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, export-to-excel

I have a table with one column, and multiple elements inside. What I am trying to do is, customize the display of data upon export.
My problem is I don't know how to re-arrange the positioning of data to excel on export.

I read about the [export options](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/38711/export-options) here and try the solution below, but nothing happens.

I made a sample code in [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gEJXXp)

My expected result/format:

```
Domain 1 - 03-27-2019
--------------------------------------
# | Keywords  | Baidu | 360 | Shenma
--------------------------------------
1 | keyword 1 |   1   |  1  |    1
--------------------------------------
2 | keyword 2 |   1   |  1  |    1
--------------------------------------

--------------------------------------
Domain 2 - 03-27-2019
--------------------------------------
# | Keywords  | Baidu | 360 | Shenma
--------------------------------------
1 | keyword 1 |   1   |  1  |    1
--------------------------------------
2 | keyword 2 |   1   |  1  |    1
```

Not sure if my expected result is possible.
hope you help me.
thanks.